# Twitter-Bootstrap 3 - Background color only between columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three columns inside a row in bootstrap. I wanted to make the whole row's background color white. When I do that, padding of that row also gets a white background, **making the row seem too wide.** **I want the color to be behind columns only, but also between them.** That's why I applied it to the whole row.

[BOOTPLY EXAMPLE](http://www.bootply.com/5YsQyOV4pK)

As you can see in that Bootply example - I want the white background to apply to those white divs and spaces between (between only!) them.

When I apply it to bootstrap columns, then their padding (left padding of the first column and right padding of the last column) is also being coloured, making the row seem wider. Same story with applying it to the row.

Is there a way to make it all look as I intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. You need an additional row that will be outside your current rows and columns. Then you add 15px of padding to that outermost row. This will make all the content inside it have a white background which won't exceed your desired layout.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row outermost">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

            <!-- COLUMNS AND ROWS -->

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outermost {
   padding-left:15px;
   padding-right:15px;
}

.outermost > .col-xs-12 > .row {
   background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this takes advantage of borders being a calculated with the width to achieve the same effect you were looking for
http://www.bootply.com/CVbu8QWsXq

Comment: So you're saying that I should get rid of bootstrap's padding and apply the border? Is that compatibile with RWD using Bootstrap? Isn't that going to cause problems?

Comment: in the example code I haven't removed the padding from any of the bootstrap elements, just used borders on .row that are 15 px (this negates the 15px negative margin on this break point) if it becomes and issue at smaller breakpoints you could wrap it in a media query like 

@media(min-width:992px) {
.row {
  background:#fff;
   border-left:15px green solid;
    border-right:15px green solid;
  }
}

Comment: It doesn't work for me. There's white color behind borders too.

Comment: Because I would like those borders to be transparent, green works only for the example when I wanted it to be more visible.